# Can a moderator change the reference to "Programmers Stack Exchange" to "Software Engineering Stack Exchange" in the custom close reason?

Tags: support, close-reasons

> Questions about software engineering unrelated to testing are off-topic here, but can be asked on Programmers Stack Exchange.

A couple of problems with this close reason:

- Programmers Stack Exchange rebranded to Software Engineering Stack Exchange in 2016. Minimally change the name in the text. Links to programmers.stackexchange.com do redirect.
- Instead of linking to the /about page, consider linking to [Software Engineering's Help Center page for on-topic questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This page is a better outline of what is on- and off-topic on Software Engineering and may help people who see the close banner understand if they should visit and ask their question.
- The current wording may imply that testing questions are off-topic on Software Engineering. Quality assurance, testing, verification, and validation are all on-topic, as long as they aren't about writing code (including test code), support for a specific product or tool, or seeking recommendations for a specific product or tool.

Answer (score 3):

This came to my attention due to a request from Thomas. As a CM I'm able to edit close reasons, which moderators can not - they can only create new reasons and remove the existing ones. Since this was a minor change, I've gone ahead and addressed the first two bullet points, though not the third, as this seems like it'd benefit from discussion on this site, where y'all are experts in how to phrase these close reasons most in-alignment with your policies.

If the changes I've made are somehow unwanted or problematic, please let me know.

As a note, since I've updated the existing close reason, you should be able to see this updated text on all questions closed for this reason historically.